# Set the static directory in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

Is it possible to set a different static directory than public/ in ruby on rails with WEBrick (like in node.js).

What I want is to listen a different directory in development and in production.

Comment: Have you had a look at [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html)?

Comment: yes but I couldn't find any "require 'webrick'" in the application. I will investigate tomorrow.